# FTP Batch file moving remote files

Tags: windows, ftp, batch-file

I have an FTP batch file that uses DOS commands to pull down some files. After I'm done pulling the files down, I would like to move the files to an archive directory on the remote server. What FTP DOS commands do I use to accomplish this?

*I wasn't clear at first but this move has to take place on the remote server.

Comment: Perhaps you should post an example of what your script does currently?

Comment: See also [FTP 'rename' command to move remote files matching wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31180849/850848).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before you pull the files down, you can use the `lcd`  (local cd) command to move to your archive directory and then pull them down directly there.  you can then `lcd` back to your working directory.

otherwise you can perform the move in your bat after your ftp session is completed.

**edit**:

in the case that your archive server is remote, your best bet is to finish your ftp session and then perform the move in your .bat.

Answer (score 0):

ftp has a rename command, that should move files remotely. I haven't tried it though