# FTP 'rename' command to move remote files matching wildcard

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I'm writing a `*.bat` file (Windows) in which I use FTP commands to get remote files back on a local machine. The remote directory includes a `archive` subdirectory in which I want to move the files once they are downloaded on the local machine.

**My script in the `*.bat` file:**

```
ftp -v -i -s:GET_FILES_FTP.txt
```

**My script in `GET_FILES_FTP.txt`:**

```
open example.com
username
password
lcd S:\
lcd repository/files
mget *.txt
rename *.txt archive/
disconnect
bye
```

Note that hostname, username and password are not those I use for real!

The TXT files are downloaded properly on the local machine.

The problem is that `rename *.txt archive/` is not interpreted and the files do not move to the `archive` file. I the command window, I get an error message:

> directory not found.

I can't find extra information better than this [doc](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm).

Any idea on how to move the files?

Answer (score 1):

The [`rename` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-rename) of the Windows `ftp.exe` does not support wildcards.

You would have to dynamically generate a script file based on a list of downloaded files with a separate `rename` command for each file.

---

Or use a different command-line FTP client that supports wildcards when renaming/moving.

For example with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) the batch file would be like:

```
winscp.com /log=winscp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@example.com" ^
    "lcd S:\" ^
    "lcd repository\files" ^
    "get *.txt" ^
    "mv *.txt archive/" ^
    "exit"
```

For details see:

- [`mv` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_mv)
- [Converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP FTP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp)

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try both options and see how it works for me. Would 'rename' command work with no wildcard? For example, moving all the files within 'files' directory into 'archive' directory?

Comment: *Would 'rename' command work with no wildcard?* No. That's (kind of) wildcard too. It can work with a specific file only.